Disabling SMT in a GKE
I'm trying to disable SMT on a GKE cluster but it doesn't seem to work when using a custom machine type.
Is there a way to do this in the deployment yaml or using a gcloud command with a restart?
I tried using a custom machine type instead of the default but that didn't work
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

There are some limitations for Simultaneous Multithreading SMT:

Machine types: SMT is not configurable on machine types that have fewer than 2 vCPUs, for example n1-standard-1 or shared-core machines such as e2-micro, e2-small, and e2-medium.

GKE node auto-provisioning: SMT configurability is not supported for clusters that have node auto-provisioning enabled.

GKE cluster autoscaler: Scaling from zero nodes with SMT configurability is only supported on clusters running GKE version 1.21 or later

Existing node pools: SMT cannot be configured on existing node pools. Only new clusters or new node pools can be created with SMT configured.

Cluster mode: SMT is not configurable on GKE Autopilot clusters.


If you have any of the above limitations in your cluster you won't be able to use SMT, for your scenario you may not configure existing clusters, you need to create a new cluster with no SMT.
Once try below method :

Create an other nodepool by using the below command:


gcloud container node-pools create demosmtpool \
  --cluster smtdemo \
  --threads-per-core=1 \
  --zone=us-central1-a


Using the above command you will create a node pool with SMT off as you have mentioned threads per core as 1.

Drain and delete the default or previous node pool which has SME enabled.

Above method is working for n1-standard-2 as I have tested, once try for a custom machine type and let me know if you face any errors.
